# Download files directly from S3 from Django site

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to serve a download link directly from S3? I have large zip files I do not want to transfer to my site instance and would prefer to serve out of S3. Is there a way to basically make a button initiate a download directly from S3?

I do not care about hiding the S3 url from the user.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're attempting to do here, files is way too generic. Are you working with filefields, static, getting files on S3 in some other way?

Comment: @DanielPettikin These are static files on S3.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response to your comment you should probably be installing django-storages and configuring according to the docs:

http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

When set up correctly it'll just switch over S3 as the backend for the built in collect_static command